# mdx hierarchy return parent and child in query

Tags: mdx, parent, hierarchy

I have the following query

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Period Key] AS 
    Axis(1).Item(1).Item(1).Hierarchy.CurrentMember.UniqueName 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Year Key] AS 
    [Dim Date].[Year].CurrentMember.UniqueName 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Valuation]
   ,[Measures].[Period Key]
   ,[Measures].[Year Key]
  } ON 0
 ,(
    [Dim Date].[Hierarchy].[Quarter].ALLMEMBERS
   ,[Dim Platform].[Platform Key].ALLMEMBERS
  ) ON 1
FROM [Cube];
```

I want the Year Key to return the uniquename in the hierarchy instead, as I want to use it in a parameter. In this form it will cause errors as the field definition is expecting the result in the hierarchy form.
Is this possible?

Comment: can you expand on this please `the uniquename in the hierarchy instead`...I'm not sure exactly of your requirements

Comment: In the above query, [Measures].[Year Key] will be in the form [Dim Date].[Year].&[2012], I want it to come back using the hierarchy setup ie [Dim Date].[Hierarchy].[Year].&[2012]. In other words I want it to match the format to match the child that is being returned, [Dim Date].[Hierarchy].[Quarter].

Comment: still a bit unsure how to interpret your request - why don't you add a measure defined as `[Dim Date].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember.UniqueName` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your hierarchy is Year-Semester-Quarter-Month-Date, how about using

```
[Dim Date].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Parent.Parent.UniqueName
```

If you have a Year-Quarter-Month-Date in place,

```
[Dim Date].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Parent.UniqueName
```

What this is doing is that it's looking at the current Quarter and returning it's corresponding year by going up in the hierarchy tree using the `.PARENT` function.

Comment: goddamn, if it isnt the simplest of solutions. Thanks mate that worked a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure of requirements but if I run the following against `AdvWrks`:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Period Key] AS 
    Axis(1).Item(1).Item(1).Hierarchy.CurrentMember.UniqueName 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Year Key] AS 
    [Date].[Calendar Year].CurrentMember.UniqueName 
  MEMBER [Measures].[New Key] AS 
    [Date].[Calendar Quarter].CurrentMember.UniqueName 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
     ,[Measures].[Period Key]
     ,[Measures].[Year Key]
     ,[Measures].[New Key]
    } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    (
      [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Quarter].ALLMEMBERS
     ,[Product].[Product Categories].ALLMEMBERS
    ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

It results in this:

[image]

Is `[New Key]` similar to what you require in your cube?

Comment: How do you display year using the calender hierarchy? so that the uniquename is in the format [Date].[Calender].[Calender Year].&[2005]